# Differences between PEP-333 and PEP-3333

Tags: python, python-3.x, wsgi

I have been reading a lot about both [PEP-333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) and [PEP-3333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/). But I still don't seem to understand the major problems in 333 that 3333 provides a solution for.

I have also seen [Armin Ronacher talk at DjangoCon 2010](http://blip.tv/djangocon-europe-2010/armin-ronacher-the-future-of-wsgi-and-python-3-3696398), where he talks about the problems with WSGI and Python 3 -- but I still can't get the gist of what he is talking about.

I also understand that the major problem in Python 3 is the strict separation between the `str` and `bytes` types, but I don't understand how it affects WSGI, and exactly how Python 3 is making it hard to deal with WSGI.

I also don't understand the differences between PEP-333 and PEP-3333, and how 3333 has ([at least for now](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/10/is-pep-3333-final-solution-for-wsgi-on.html)) solved the problems for Python 3.

Please explain all the issues in (great) detail.

Comment: I'd say http://svn.python.org/view/peps/trunk/pep-3333.txt?r1=84854&r2=HEAD should give you a (perhaps slightly too) detailed picture of the changes.

Comment: You are asking for a lot of effort for a good answer, but you have only accepted answers to 1/3 of your questions.  You need to either ask better questions to get answers you can accept, or accept the good answers you already have.

Comment: @EthanFurman Since when did Stackoverflow become a reputation only game? I thought exchanging information and helping each other on technology related issues was more important than trying to reap more reputation from each answer that you contribute.

Comment: Of the first four unaccepted questions: one I have no experience in and three looked like they had acceptable answers.  It's not about reputation, it's about you doing your part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some background of the issues read:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/09/roadmap-for-python-wsgi-specification.html

The final set of changes to the PEP don't necessarily match exactly any specific set of proposals in that document, but may bring some insight.